# Solver of proof in Dymola

Tags: solver, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am new with Dymola but do you know if a solver of proof exists in Dymola. I am looking for a solver like SLDV in Simulink. SLDV is used in order to identify hidden design errors in models.  It can formally verify that the design meets functional requirements. For each design error or requirements violation, it generates a simulation test case for debugging. Also SLDV generates test cases for model coverage and custom objectives to extend existing requirements-based test cases.

Thank you for your answer,

Eloise

Comment: Is this related to programming or a general software question? You might want to try superuser.com instead.

Comment: This refers to something like formal verification or test generation/running tools for the Modelica language, so is I think quite in scope here, considering things like [formal-verification] or [pytest] are existing tags here.

Answer (score 4):

There are libraries available for requirement verification. Although not exactly as you describe. Some papers about such libraries can be found here
[here](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/Modelica_Requirements) and [here](https://ep.liu.se/ecp/108/018/ecp14108018.pdf)

A Modelica requirement library named *Modelica_Requirements* may be found [here](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/Modelica_Requirements)